# how to optimize nearest neighbor query in postgis within given distance?

Tags: python, flask, geolocation, postgis, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the following Nearest Neighbor Query in PostGIS with Flask-SQLAlchemy :

```
def get_neighbor():
    pt = WKTElement('POINT(%s %s)' % (longitude, latitude), srid=srid)

    # Get total count of neighbor with distance less than 1000m for example.
    total_count = db.session.query(User, func.ST_Distance(User.geom, pt)). \
        filter(func.ST_DWith(User.geom, pt, 1000).count()

    if total_count > 0:
        result_list = db.session.query(User, func_ST_Distance(User.geom, pt)). \
            filter(func.ST_DWithin(User.geom, pt, 1000).all()

        return jsonify({'total_count': total_count, 'result_list':result_list})
    else
        return jsonify({'total_count': total_count})
```

It works fine actually, but I've noticed the same query statements will be executed twice when querying **total_count** and **result_list**.

1. How to optimize the repeated query problem in **total_count** and **result_list**?
2. When User table contains thousands of rows, will the query compare every row in User table with given point? If so, that would be slow performance, How do I solve this?

any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Flask-SQLAlchemy, but what you want is [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), which is optimized to find geometries within a distance, and can use GiST indexes. This is better than finding the distances to *all* geometries with ST_Distance.

As it seems you have SRID=4326, you would either need to use `geography` types to get metric distance results, or can cast `geometry` to that type:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user
WHERE ST_DWithin(user.geom::geography, 'SRID=4326;POINT(-122.4 37.7)'::geography, 1000.0);
```

you can create a spatial index on that cast with something like:

```
CREATE INDEX user_geog_idx ON user USING gist ((geom::geography));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll try it. :)